# TFS query param "Assigned to" equals to selected user

Tags: tfs, scrumboard

I want to add in TFS query where parameter "Assigned to" will be equal to team member selected from dropdown list This oportunity exists in Work/Query. There will be great if I can put such query on overview.

I cannot find this option, is it possible? I'm using TFS 2015.

Answer (score 0):

> *Derrick Fu MSFT*  @Brett – sorry for the frustration. **With TFS2015, we
>   shipped a new user picking experience designed around an MRU list and
>   search experience. The “random” list of users you are seeing is
>   actually the most recent users you have assigned work items to.** For
>   scoped person fields, we realize this is a bit of a takeback since you
>   no longer get a scoped list of users.
>
> If you want, you can ***re-enable the old picking experience*** (without
>   MRU, search, and avatars) by running the following command on your TFS
>   instance:  exec prc_SetRegistryValue 1,
>   ‘#\Service\WorkItemTracking\Settings\UseTextControlForIdentityFields\’, true
>
> This will change all person fields across the collection back to the
>    old behavior.
>
> Source Link: [VS2015 Update 2 and TFS 2015 Update 2 have shipped](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bharry/2016/03/31/vs2015-update-2-and-tfs-2015-update-have-shipped/)

There also has been a uservocie- [Limit items in Assigned To Drop down to ALLOWEDVALUES in Web interface](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/10205670-limit-items-in-assigned-to-drop-down-to-allowedval) you can vote up it to get more attention.